# The current path didnt match any of these Error when adding a link to a button

Tags: django, django-urls

Been trying to add a link and it keeps sending me errors although the templates are working.

Views.py

```
def store(request):
context = {}
return render(request, 'store/store.html', context)


def cart(request):
context = {}
return render(request, 'store/cart.html', context)


def checkout(request):
context = {}
return render(request, 'store/checkout.html', context)
```

Urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', include('store.urls'))
]
```

main.html

```
<a class="nav-link" href="{$ url 'cart' %}">Store <span class="sr-only"> 
(current)</span></a>
<a class="nav-link" href="{$ url 'store' %}">Store <span class="sr-only"> 
(current)</span></a>
<a class="nav-link" href="{$ url 'checkout' %}">Store <span class="sr-only"> 
(current)</span></a>
```

Store.urls

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
path('', views.store, name='store'),
path('cart/', views.cart, name='cart'),
path('checkout/', views.checkout, name='checkout'),
```

]

the url route sends me an error but I can access to the templates by 127.0.0.1:8000/cart and 127.0.0.1:8000/ works for store and 127.0.0.1:8000/checkout works for checkout. but I can not access thru the links

Comment: How does the `store.urls` look like?

Comment: added store.urls

Comment: You have`$` chars instead of`%` in your url tags. `{$ url 'cart' %}` should be `{% url 'cart' %}`

Comment: You have a typo on `href="{$ url 'store' %}"`  **$** must be **%**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try correcting some typos in the href of your main.html: % instead of $.

it should be:

```
<a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'cart' %}">Store <span class="sr-only"> 
(current)</span></a>
<a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'store' %}">Store <span class="sr-only"> 
(current)</span></a>
<a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'checkout' %}">Store <span class="sr-only"> 
(current)</span></a>
```